# How to use Sql server connection in angular 6?

Tags: sql-server, angular6

I have do connection in 'Angular6' using `sqlserver`.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'abc',
        password: 'abc',
        server: 'servername', 
        database: 'xyz' 
    };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
           
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from tbl', function (err, recordset) {
            
            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  }
  getUser(userId) {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+userId)
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  }

  getPhotos()
  {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  }

  getTodos()
  {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  }
}
```

Right now I have used dummy API'S for result.
how to get my database results in service?
I have successfully get result from Sqlserver database.

I also want to display record in my Component

**user.component.html**

```
<h1>Users</h1>
```

Can I have to import server.js in `user.component.ts`.
If yes than how can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding angular. Angular run into browser and its context is limited to that.

If you need to connect to a database, you need to use some backend technologies, like express and nodejs, as the code you posted.

The main way is to expose some backend services, like REST services, developed with a server side techonology (nodejs, j2ee, php, etc) and then use Angular to ask them for data.

Generally to achieve this goal in angular you should use `HttpClient`

You should search for a tutorial, like [this](https://appdividend.com/2018/05/27/angular-6-crud-example-mean-stack-tutorial/)

**Angular example to request data**

In angular you should create a service class to call your exposed service, then into that class you could create a method like this:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {catchError, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get([YOUR_BACKEND_SERVICE_URL]).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError(`get`))
      );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
     return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      console.error(error);

      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      return of(result as T);
     };
   }
}
```

Then you should write a component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.testService.get().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

}
```

You need to create service and component with `AngularCli` in order to avoid to manually declare and import them into `app.module.ts`

For a better understanding of what is happening I suggest you to read [Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial, Services section](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: if i want this data into my component than how can i achieve?

Comment: i have post my service please check it. its with dummy `API`

Comment: `[YOUR_BACKEND_SERVICE_URL]` Means which url?

Comment: I don't know which url have you configured in your backend app.  You should have a line like this: server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1'); They are port and eventually hotname or ip. You could have only first param that means localhost for hostname

Comment: i have used `node server.js` for get data from `sql`. and when i run localhost:5000 its display data in json formate.

Comment: Ok, so you must replace your dummy api URL with localhost:5000. Then when you will add more app.get() mapping you should add these URL to different methods into your angular service. Now it's clear?

Comment: yeah got it!! thanks to give your valuable time to explain me!!

Comment: @KiranJoshi [YOUR_BACKEND_SERVICE_URL] is an url for json data of your application. Json file contain either data from database or you can have your own data model.